# Instrument a recursive async function with opentelemetry

Tags: rust, async-await, open-telemetry

I would like to instrument a recursive function with opentelemetry, here is a minimal reproducible example:

```rust
use futures::future::{BoxFuture, FutureExt};
use opentelemetry::global;
use opentelemetry::trace::Tracer;
use std::{thread, time};
use tokio;
use tracing::{info, instrument};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    number: usize,
}

#[instrument]
fn recursive<'a>(foo: &'a mut Foo) -> BoxFuture<'a, usize> {
    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(333));
    async move {
        if foo.number == 0 {
            return 0;
        }
        foo.number -= 1;
        recursive(foo).await
    }
    .boxed()
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    global::set_text_map_propagator(opentelemetry_zipkin::Propagator::new());
    let tracer = opentelemetry_zipkin::new_pipeline()
        .install_simple()
        .unwrap();

    let mut start = Foo { number: 3 };
    let _ = recursive(&mut start).await;

    global::shutdown_tracer_provider();
    dbg!(&start);
}
```

I get a panic at runtime with the message:

```
Cannot drop a runtime in a context where blocking is not allowed. This happens when a runtime is dropped from within an asynchronous context.
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I also tried applying what was described here:
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-rust/blob/bd3ba65546217ef654b9e5edb32b783a2f1af95c/opentelemetry/src/trace/mod.rs#L163C5-L163C63

But wasn't able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dug into it and found that `opentelemetry_zipkin::new_pipeline()` by default creates a blocking [reqwest](https://crates.io/crates/reqwest) `Client` which [documents](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/blocking/struct.Client.html#method.new) that:

> This method also panics if called from within an async runtime. See docs on `reqwest::blocking` for details.

There are a few workarounds:

1. You can delay creating your asynchronous runtime until needed, letting build-up and tear-down code (like creating and shutting down the tracer) stay synchronous:

   ```
   #[tokio::main]
   async fn start() {
       let mut start = Foo { number: 3 };
       let _ = recursive(&mut start).await;
       dbg!(&start);
   }

   fn main() {
       global::set_text_map_propagator(opentelemetry_zipkin::Propagator::new());
       let tracer = opentelemetry_zipkin::new_pipeline()
           .install_simple()
           .unwrap();

       start();

       global::shutdown_tracer_provider();
   }
   ```
2. You can tell opentelemetry-zipkin to use the asynchronous reqwest `Client` like so:

   ```ini
   opentelemetry-zipkin = { version = "0.19.0", default_features = false, features = ["reqwest-client"] }
   ```

   The default uses the `"reqwest-blocking-client"` feature.